# Processing-video 3.0.1 - broken Maven artifacts?

Tags: scala, sbt, processing

I am trying to figure out whether I can update a Processing sketch from 2.2.1 to 3.0.1, because of some Gstreamer library version problem. To me it looks like somebody messed up big time with publishing [Maven artifacts](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.processing|video|3.0.1|jar). What I see is for example this:

[image]

That is to say, processing-video 3.0.1 seems to have been compiled perhaps with an incompatible version of `PImage`? When I compile my project with sbt, I see these warnings/errors:

```
Error:scalac: Class PApplet not found - continuing with a stub.
Warning:scalac: Class PApplet not found - continuing with a stub.
Warning:scalac: Class PImage not found - continuing with a stub.
```

When my only dependencies are:

```
"org.processing" % "core"  % "3.0.1"
"org.processing" % "video" % "3.0.1"
```

Comment: It sure sounds like the wrong dependency is being included. Unfortunately I don't know anything about scala. Do you have a pom.xml I could try on my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing is now at 3.2.3, and probably this problem has disappeared.